# List Comprehension table filtering

Tags: python, list-comprehension

"Use list comprehensions to filter the hours table to include only managers."

I have two tables: hours & titles

```
hours = [["Alice", 43], ["Bob", 37], ["Fred", 15]]
titles = [["Alice", "Manager"], ["Betty", "Consultant"], ["Bob", "Assistant"]]
```

I need to filter the hours table down to only the managers using a list comprehension. So far I have used titles to create a separate table with the names of the managers using get from toolz

```
from toolz import get
manager_list = [i for i in titles if get(-1,i) == "Manager"]
```

which produces `[['Alice', 'Manager']]`

Now I am trying to take my manager_list table and compare it with the hours table to only keep the entries with the same names in manager_list. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do that. I keep just getting empty tables.

What I have right now is `manager_hours = [i for i in hours if get(0,i) in manager_list]` but it does not work, I cannot figure out how to compare the two.

The end result I'm looking for is `[['Alice', 43]]` but I don't know how to get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data might not be accurate is using `filter`

```
names = [x for x, y in titles if y == "Manager"]
managers = [(x, y) for (x, y) in hours if x in names]
```

DEMO:

```
>>> names = [x for x, y in titles if y == "Manager"]
>>> names
['Alice']
>>> managers = [(x, y) for (x, y) in hours if x in names]
>>> managers
[('Alice', 43)]
```

Another way to do this, Assuming you will have the 2 lists with the same set of "names", and the length, One thing you could do is to combine the 2 lists using `zip`.

Something like this:

```
hours = [["Alice", 43], ["Bob", 37], ["Fred", 15]]
titles = [["Alice", "Manager"], ["Betty", "Consultant"], ["Bob", "Assistant"]]

managers = [(x, y) for ((x, y), (z, w)) in zip(hours, titles) if w == "Manager"]
```

Comment: Glad it helped. If the answer was useful, do mark the answer as accepted. The "Green Tick mark" next to the answer that helped you the best.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a temporary set to get the managers by themselves, then filter by that:

```
hours = [["Alice", 43], ["Bob", 37], ["Fred", 15]]
titles = [["Alice", "Manager"], ["Betty", "Consultant"], ["Bob", "Assistant"]]

managers = set(l[0] for l in titles if l[1] == "Manager")

managers
Out[4]: {'Alice'}

manager_hours = [l for l in hours if l[0] in managers]

manager_hours
Out[6]: [['Alice', 43]]
```

However, in terms of design, you might want to think about using `dict`s to hold your data. It's the right data structure for key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `titles` list a dictionary, and then filter your `hours` list by looking up the `title` dictionary:

```
title_d = dict(titles)    
[i for i in hours if title_d.get(i[0]) == "Manager"]
# [['Alice', 43]]
```